# How to setText to ArrayList<>?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I have a class Tweet with a get Mentions methods with it 
But I don't know how to setText to the ArrayList<>.
Here is my code

```
public class Tweet {

    public String body;
    private long uid;
    private String createAt;
    private User user;
    private String urlImageNews;
    private static String url;
    public ArrayList<User> mentions;
    public ArrayList<User> getMentions()
    {
        return mentions;
    }
    public String getUrlImageNews()
    {
        return urlImageNews;
    }
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public long getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public String getCreateAt() {
        return createAt;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public String getUrl()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public String getRelativeTimeAgo() {
        String twitterFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(twitterFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
        sf.setLenient(true);

        String relativeDate = "";
        try {
            long dateMillis = sf.parse(getCreateAt()).getTime();
            relativeDate = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(dateMillis,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS).toString();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return relativeDate;
    }
    public static Tweet fromJSON(JSONObject jsonObject)
    {
        Tweet twt = new Tweet();
        try {
            twt.body = jsonObject.getString("text");
            twt.uid = jsonObject.getLong("id");
            twt.createAt = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
            twt.user = User.fromJSON(jsonObject.getJSONObject("user"));
            twt.mentions = LoadMentions(jsonObject);
            JSONArray media = jsonObject.getJSONObject("entities").optJSONArray("media");
            if (media != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < media.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject a = media.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (a.getString("type").equals("photo")) {
                        twt.urlImageNews = a.getString("media_url_https");

                    }

                }
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return twt;
    }
    private static ArrayList<User> LoadMentions(JSONObject object) throws JSONException{
        if (!object.getJSONObject("entities").has("user_mentions")) {
            return  null;
        }

        ArrayList<User> mentions = new ArrayList<User>();
        JSONArray mentionsJSON = object.getJSONObject("entities").getJSONArray("user_mentions");
        for (int i = 0; i < mentionsJSON.length(); i++) {
            User user = User.fromJSON(mentionsJSON.getJSONObject(i));
            mentions.add(user);
        }
        return mentions;

    }
    public static ArrayList<Tweet> fromJSONArray(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            try {
                JSONObject tweetjson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Tweet tweet = Tweet.fromJSON(tweetjson);
                if(tweet != null)
                {

                    tweets.add(tweet);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }
        }
        return tweets;
        }
}
```

Here is my MentionsAdapter where I want to setText the Mentions Array

```
public class MentionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MentionsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    View tweetView;

    private List<Tweet> lTweets;

    public MentionsAdapter(List<Tweet> tweets)
    {
        lTweets = tweets;
    }


    public void clear() {
        lTweets.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // Add a list of items
    public void addAll(List<Tweet> list) {
        lTweets.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private ImageView ivProfile;
        private TextView tvUsername;
        private TextView tvMentions;
        private TextView tvMentionsDate;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ivProfile = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivAva);
            tvUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvMentions = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMentions);
            tvMentionsDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMentionsDate);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        tweetView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_metions, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(tweetView);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("debug", "int:: " + position);
        Tweet tweet = lTweets.get(position);
        holder.tvMentionsDate.setText(tweet.getRelativeTimeAgo());
        holder.tvUsername.setText(tweet.getUser().getName());
        holder.tvMentions.setText(tweet)
        holder.ivProfile.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        Glide.with(context).load(tweet.getUser().getProfileImageUrl()).into(holder.ivProfile);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(lTweets == null){
            Log.d("debug", "null");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            Log.d("debug", ":: " + lTweets.size());
            return lTweets.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly you want to do with tvMentions ??

Comment: Well actually I'm trying to setText the mentions but I can't . Like I want to print out the data from the twt.mentions = LoadMentions(jsonObject); But I don't know how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh Well I fix with my answer just by adding some line :
twt.textMentions = jsonObject.getString("text");
Anyway thanks everyone for the answers

Answer (score 0):

you can get mentions data from tweet by following

```
        User user = tweet.getMentions();
```

so that you can get user object from that.same way you can get all user instances from here by using

```
        user.getMethodName()
```

just update the above code in onBindViewHolder().

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Log.d("debug", "int:: " + position);
            Tweet tweet = lTweets.get(position);
            User user = tweet.getMentions();

            holder.tvMentionsDate.setText(tweet.getRelativeTimeAgo());
            holder.tvUsername.setText(tweet.getUser().getName());
            holder.tvMentions.setText(tweet)
            holder.ivProfile.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            Glide.with(context).load(tweet.getUser().getProfileImageUrl()).into(holder.ivProfile);
        }
```

Comment: Yeah I update my method with your User user = tweet.getMentions(); but I can't add it to . holder.tvMentions.setText(user).

Comment: you can call holder.tvMentions.setText(user.getMethodName()).Here the methodName() should be user class defined..

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply Malli seems like I fix it :D

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong u want to add data to your ArrayList which is of type Tweet this can be done like this

```
yourArrayList.add(new Tweet ("Parameters goes here");
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you just want to display the number of mentions. 
you can do this:

```
holder.tvMentions.setText(Integer.toString(tweet.getMentions().size()));
```

Comment: Yeah but I want to print out the String that people mentions me. Like this @dq1078: Blablabla

Comment: then you have to loop throught the ArrayList elements like
String label = "";
for(int i=0; i<tweet.getMentions().size(); i++) {
    label += tweet.getMentions().get(i).username + " " + tweet.getMentions().get(i).comment;
}